# How to create MP4 video using frames array in openCV that is playable in HTML5

Tags: python, html, opencv, base64, mp4

I need to create a video file that I can convert to base64 string and play it in an HTML5 page.
I am using openCV to read frames from my webcam that I store inside an array of frames. I need to create videos of 16 frames that I can then convert to string base64. This base64 string I want to use in an HTML page as a video tag source.
I've managed to create an MP4 video file using openCV:

```
width = 400
height = 300
out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 10, (width, height))
for frame in frames:
    out.write(frame)
out.release()
```

This is creating me an MP4 video file at the 'video.mp4' path that has 10 fps. The video is working fine by opening it with a media player.
But when I tried creating an HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <video controls autoplay loop>
            <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Chrome Browser is showing me this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee9S7.png)
which is not playable. When I try with any other MP4 file it is working just fine.
I think the problem is with the video file generated using openCV because I don't have any audio codec to it.

I compared de description of the openCV generated MP4 file and a normal MP4 file and it shows clearly that there is no audio codec to the one that is not working in HTML5:

[MP4 video file created in openCV and not working in HTML5:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO43a.png)

[Normal MP4 video file recorded with my mobile camera that works in HTML5:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98U7p.png)

So my question is: Is there any solution that I can play my MP4 video file generated using openCV cv2.VideoWriter() in a HTML5 page or how can I add an audio codec to this file?

My main goal is to create a video out of frames read from webcam with openCV and to encode it to base64 string so I can later use it in the HTML5 page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <video  width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
            <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlz...">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am open to any other solution that finally is giving me a base64 string that put in the video tag source is playing the video composed out of the webcam frames read in openCV.

I read the official openCV docs about creating a video and it says ["No audio or other track editing support here. Nevertheless, any video codec present on your system might work. If you encounter some of these limitations you will need to look into more specialized video writing libraries such as FFmpeg or codecs as HuffYUV, CorePNG and LCL. As an alternative, create the video track with OpenCV and expand it with sound tracks or convert it to other formats by using video manipulation programs such as VirtualDub or AviSynth."](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d9e/tutorial_video_write.html)
But I need to create that video encoded in base64 just with python code so I don't know how this information could help me.

I am also considering creating a blob from images (there is a cv2.dnn.blobFromImages() method) but I don't know how to use it and how to play the resulted video in browser.

This is also my first posted question ever.

Comment: **(1)** Can you provide a link to your not working video? The issue might the codec type or container format or something else... (2) Why add Base64 instead of just a playing the file?